# Strange Poisson process problem without having the mean parameter

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I found a problem of probability which asks:

> The arrival of clients to a bank can be considered as a Poisson process with parameter L. It is given that 4 clients arrived in the last hour. Considering this, find the probability that 2 of the clients arrived in the first 30 minutes and the other 2 in the last 30 minutes of that hour.

The supposed correct answer is given (p = 0,375) but I was trying to solve the problem, and I think that in the original statement is missing L. What I tried to do is to apply the definition of conditional probability. Let:

$$P(N(t)=n) = \frac{(Lt)^n}{n!} e^{-Lt}$$

be the probability that n clients arrive in a time t. Then, I consider that the time starts to count since the first client came, so the probability I should be looking for is:

$$ \frac{P(N(1/2)=1)}{P(N(1)=3)} = \frac{(L/2) e^{-L/2}}{\frac{(L)^3}{3!} e^{-L}} $$

I can't see how to simplify L. Am I doing wrong something or there is missing information?

Comment: Each $30$ minute period is the same as any other, as far as Poisson knows.  In particular, each client has an equal chance of arriving in either half.  $L$ doesn't matter.

Comment: Worth pointing out:  you appear to be computing the a priori probability that some number of people arrive in some given block of time.  That's not relevant here.  We know how many people arrived, namely $4$.  It doesn't matter if this was likely or not, we are told it happened and we start from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\lambda$ be the expected number of clients in a half-hour period.

The probability that $2$ arrive in the first half-hour is $$\frac{e^{-\lambda}
\lambda^2}{2!}$$ and likewise for the second half-hour.

The probability that $4$ arrive in a one-hour period is $$\frac{e^{2\lambda}(2\lambda)^4}{4!}$$

So the conditional probability you require is $$\left(\frac{e^{-\lambda}
\lambda^2}{2!}\right)^2\div \left(\frac{e^{2\lambda}(2\lambda)^4}{4!}\right)$$
$$=\frac38$$

All the $\lambda$ terms cancel.

Answer (score 1):

Since ‘each 30
minute period is the same as any other, as far as Poisson knows’, consider that the probability that each client arrived in the first 30 minutes is p=0,5. The correct answer is found if we apply the Binomial distribution:

$$ Combinatory(4,2) \cdot 0.5^{2} \cdot 0.5² = 0.375$$

Thanks @lulu! Love you!

Comment: But I don't think time was meant to start with the first client.  The way I see it, each client arrives in either half with probability $\frac 12$.  Thus the probability that exactly two of them arrive in the first half is $\binom 42\times \left(\frac 12\right)^4=\frac 38$.

Comment: For instance, if the problem asked "given that exactly one client showed up in the last hour, what is the probability that they showed up in the last half hour?" the answer would be $\frac 12$, not $0$ as it would be if we started the clock when the client appeared.

Comment: @lulu nice observation :)